# Best way to parallelize a non-IO task using many physical cores: Equal work per thread, or maximum number of threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

We have a variety of tasks which are separable into units of equal work and do not involve disk or network I/O.

Imagine we're trying to process 70 images.  We can process each image independently.  In the past we'd do that like this:

- Number of work units: 70
- Number of cores: 16
- Work per thread = ceil(70/16) = 5
- Number of threads = 70 / 5 = 14 threads.

You'll notice that this algorithm appears to "waste" two cores on such a high core count machine.  So it was proposed that this might be better:

- Number of threads = Number of cores = 16
- Work per thread = 5 (for 6 threads) or 4 (for 10 threads)

Upon further analysis, this seems like it might not be beneficial:

1. If the tasks are CPU bound, the wall-time to run everything only
   depends on the thread with the most work, which is still 5.
2. If the tasks are memory bound, adding more threads will just increase contention.  Worse, we'll be left with only 5 threads running at the end, which might not be able to saturate the memory bus anymore.
3. Algorithm 2 doesn't leave any spare cores for OS or background work.

Note that we do not want to allocate a task object for each image.  It doesn't matter here, but in other cases we may have many images and don't want to have to pay to allocate an object for every one.   In either of these two algorithms, we only have to allocate a Runnable that captures two integers per thread.  We perform the actual execution of the Runnable in a fixed-size ThreadPoolExecutor.

I do wonder what other implementations like ForkJoinPool or Grand Central Dispatch might do in this case, though.

## Questions:

- Are there reasons to prefer the second algorithm over the first?  What are they?
- Is there a consensus that one is better than the other "on average"?  Why?

We're programming in Java but I believe this question applies to any language with shared memory threads.

Comment: Have you considered a [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html)? It's not really clear what your question is really about.

Comment: Not sure what a "work unit" is, but it sounds like a "task", so use an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and call the `submit(task)` method *(the `ForkJoinPool` mentioned by Elliott Frisch is an `ExecutorService`)*.

Comment: We usually don't use ForkJoinPool because the number of tasks can sometimes be large and the overhead of task creation becomes a problem.  Either algorithm I discussed has memory allocation O(# threads), not O(# work units).  For example, if we want to process 70 images, we can just tell thread 1 to process indexes [0,4] in the list.  ForkJoinPool is sometimes useful in other cases, where the amount work that needs done is not similar between the units.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if each image can be processed independently, and you have 70 images, why don't you just create 70 process-the-image-tasks, submit them all to a thread pool queue (e.g. `ExecutorService`), and let the threads process the tasks as they can? You mention something about the number of tasks being an overhead; if that's the case, why not have a producer/consumer setup so that only so many tasks are created at a time?

Comment: It's not about allocating so many tasks at a time, it's about allocating so many tasks at all.  In this example it doesn't matter, but imagine if we were processing several million 16x16 images.  Millions of task objects would be created and potentially promoted to the old generation before the execution was completed.  In contrast with the two algorithms above, which only allocate a Runnable and two Integers per thread.  We do use a fixed size ThreadPoolExecutor to perform the actual threaded execution of the work.  I'll edit the question to make this more clear.

Comment: Have you profiled an actual problem with the garbage collector when so many tasks are created, even if created lazily?

Comment: Yes.  As an example, it's about 3-5% slower in our image reconstruction workflow, which should be pretty good for ForkJoinPool as we only allocate <64 tasks at a time.  But the process involves millions of allocations, overhead to manage them, etc.  Other workflows that allocate more and/or shorter lived tasks can be worse.  ForkJoinPool is better in cases where there are unknown or heterogenous task lengths, that's just not a common case for us (we do use it occasionally).